# Gson from JSON to HashMap<Integer, MyObject> where Integer is inside of JSON object

Tags: java, json, parsing, hashmap, gson

I have a JSON string that I'm trying to parse into a HashMap.

My object looks like this:

```
public class MyObject {

private int id;
private String text;
}
```

and the JSON string looks like this:

```
objects:[
{"id":1, "text":"firsttext"},
{"id":2, "text":"secondtext"},
{"id":3, "text":"thirdtext"}
]
```

How would I go about neatly parsing this into a HashMap< Integer, MyObject > so that if I was to call HashMap.get(2) the second object of the array containing "secondtext" would return?

Right now what I'm doing is

```
Type integerStringMap = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, MyObject>>(){}.getType();
HashMap<Integer, MyObject> objects = new Gson().fromJson(content, integerStringMap);
```

But I'm getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id".

I'm feeling pretty clueless as how to solve this without loops and I'm really hoping there's a more clever way to do this. Would appreciate any help!

EDIT: Here is a snippet of code that does what I want:

```
Type integerObjectList = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType();

List<MyObject> cardList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, integerObjectList);

HashMap<Integer, MyObject> cardMap = new HashMap<Integer, MyObject>();
for (MyObject o : objectList) {
    objectMap.put(o.getId(), o);
}
```

I would if possible want to do it without the for loop.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/convert-json-to-from-map-jackson/).

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me. Maybe there is a problem in how you created the 'content' ?

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        String jsonStr = "[{'id':1, 'text':'firsttext'}," +
                "{'id':2, 'text':'secondtext'}," +
                "{'id':3, 'text':'thirdtext'}]";

        Type integerStringMap = new TypeToken<Collection<MyObject>>(){}.getType();
        Collection<MyObject> enums = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, integerStringMap);

        for(MyObject mo : enums){
            System.out.println(mo);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think I explained what I'm trying to achieve well enough. I edited my original post to show what I'd like to do.